# Why does the line integral of $r \,d\theta$ from $0$ to $2\pi$ equal $0$?

Tags: calculus

In my electromagnetism course we are told that the line integral:

$\int_0^{2\pi} \hat{\theta} r \,d\theta = 0$, where $\hat{\theta}$ is the unit vector in cylindrical coordinates orthogonal to $\hat{r}$.

Shouldn't the answer be $2\pi r$ instead? Why is it zero? I'm confused trying to figure this out.

Also, I've never seen a line integral of this form before.  The only line integrals I've seen have either been scalar or a dot product between two vectors.  What is this line integral?

Comment: Try to write the coordinates of $\hat{\theta}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $\hat r = r(\cos θ,\sin θ)$ you get $\hat θ=(-\sinθ,\cosθ)$ and integrating these trigonometric functions over a full period gives always the value $0$.

Or you could split the integral in the middle and observe that $ \hat θ(θ)+\hat θ(θ+\pi)=0$, so that the integral over the half circle of the sum stays zero.

Comment: When we do the integral, can we factor out unit vectors like x and y since they are always pointing in the same direction, regardless of $\theta$?

Comment: If you mean the vectors $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$, then yes, since they are constants.